# Turning on MOSFET and sensing to microcontroller input pin

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, mosfet

I've got a stereojack, and I'd like to turn on an LED and also make an input pin to a microcontroller HIGH (For interrupt sensing).
The Vs is 3.3v
The [LED](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Hubei-KENTO-Elec-Green-0805-Iv-207-249-mcd-atIF-20mA_C2297.pdf) has a Vf of 2.9v
The [MOSFET](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Changjiang-Electronics-Tech-CJ-2N7002_C8545.pdf) has a gate threshold of 1v

I'd like to at least protect the GND pin from a short (Since the jack tip can touch the ring when inserting I've heard), so I've added a 1K series resistor to limit current.
Now this obviously makes a `3.3v -> 10K ->0.3v -> 1K -> 0v` voltage divider. Am I right in thinking that this 0.3v LOW signal is ok? Both to keep the MOSFET Drain-Source closed and also for the microcontroller pin to be seen digitally as "LOW".

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've noticed there has to be a 0.7v drop across the diode! Hmm, is there a way to protect the input pin from any unwanted reverse voltage coming from the sleeve without dropping that voltage?

EDIT: I've removed the diode to remove that 0.7V and added a schottky instead

EDIT3: I've taken out the schottky, just added  a TVS to clamp any unwanted transient voltages to 3.3

[image]

Comment: Use a small signal Schottky for D3 (like the BAS581).

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the jack plug is intended to do or where the MCU connects. What are the green notes referring to? You can protect the MCU pin with a 100 kohm series resistor and forget about the diodes.

Comment: Ah - Thanks @ScienceGeyser, that's what I'm looking for! Andy - the ring is not connected to the other end, it's just the sleeve and tip that I'm using for signal. I'm using the sleeve for presence detection because I can ground it. Is that helpful?
EDIT: The MCU connects to CT1 presence, the green notes are relevant info from both the MOSFET and LED datasheet

Comment: No, what does the jack plug connect to? What signal is being fed in?

Comment: The signal is a driven current from a current transducer, two terminals from each end of the CT coil are connected to pins 1 and 5 on the Jack connector. Pin 2 is not connected

Comment: If you are making this yourself, why not use the ring and sleeve for the sensor and the tip for detection? This way you don't bounce the detection during insert and you don't have to worry about any sort of analog signal on your digital lines.

Comment: I'm not making it myself unfortunately! It's an [off-the-shelf component](https://www.bitsbox.co.uk/data/sensors/SCT013-000.pdf)

Comment: Only 50 mV on the output... I wouldn't worry too much about that and the device has a TVS for it's own protection. Is there a TRS connector on the sensor from the factory?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! So just leave the protection? Yeah I spotted that TVS but I think it's rated for a fair bit more than 3.3v. The 50mV is only when there's a burden resistor across the terminals. If someone plugs this in while it's live, then the TVS will be clamping to whatever they clamp to! Think it'll still be okay?

Comment: If the datasheet doesn't specify the TVS value, you could try measuring the value to see what it is. I would think the manufacturer would want to clamp as close as possible to the expected output voltage. Their specification does seem odd. It's possible that they mean the output is up to 50 mA instead of 50 mV, in which case, you need your protection and the right load resistance to make the measurement. At that current you would need 60 Ohms to get 3V full scale.

Comment: Yeah - thanks for the clarification - I've got a 22Ohm burden for 300A max pk-pk. I've done away with the diode protecting the pin, and instead I'm clamping all 3 pins to 3.3 with a unidirectional TVS each to ground. [Here's the updated schematic](https://imgur.com/a/fuQ12wT)